# Creating Evaluated Field in Django By Applying Aggregation On 2 Fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, derived

I am in phase of learning Django framework and I need some help to understand how to generate an evaluated field by summing up two inputs by user. I've used the code below where `ops1` and `ops2` will be provided by user and I need to show their sum in field `total_ops` at runtime. I've used the code below but that doesn't seems to work.

```
class ManHour(models.Model):
    date      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Operations(models.Model):
         ops1  = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3)
         ops2  = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3)
    
    total_ops = Operations.ops1 + Operations.ops2
```

Error from code above

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute'
```

Comment: do you want a column in operations named total_ops ? as per the post you have written the logic to add in model

Comment: @Neeraj I would have `operations` column in db and this will also be an evaluated field when user inputs data he must get a sum of `ops1` and `ops2` in field `operations`

Comment: in that case can you share your viewset or form which you have used to save op1 and op2?

Comment: @Neeraj I am new to Django so I don't know if I am doing correct. I am first creating a model which I've shown in my question and after creating my model I am testing my input by logging into /admin page and adding objects. I haven't created any form or view yet.

Comment: ah okay.. your models are the skeleton of your database tables. so total_ops would be DecimalField as well. and the addition of ops would take place in forms/viewsets/serializer(if DRF) while you save the objects

Answer (score 0):

Models are where you define the fields and its attributes.

So total_ops would be a DecimalField.

Now you can apply the business logic in models. But its recommended to save it using viewsets or forms.

Since you are still learning, and for this specific query you can do something like this:

```
class Operations(models.Model):
     ops1  = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3)
     ops2  = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3)
     total_ops = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3)

     def save(self):
         self.total_ops = self.ops1 + self.ops2
         return super(Operations, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to calculate a field based on other fields of a model object, you should use `F()` expressions. It is described on the django docs at
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F)

So if you want to save a field with the value of another field, it should look like:

```
operations  # Model instance
operations.total_ops = F("ops1") + F("ops2")
operations.save()
```

Doing so inside the `save()` method is risky because it is not performed when using `queryset.update()`, `queryset.create()`, `queryset.bulk_create()`, etc.

Performing an action before saving an object should be done using `pre_save` signal, there you could modify the instance fields before it is being saved:

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def save_calculated_field(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    instance.total_ops = F("ops1") + F("ops2")
```

But it is too not recommended on most cases because signals are not executed on `queryset.create()`, `queryset.update()`, etc.

**Soooo, how to do this???**

Use `annotate` to calculate field value in database when querying, and skip saving it to database all along

```
from django.db.models import F

Operations.objects.annotate(
    total_ops=F("ops1") + F("ops2"),
)
```